# Waiting for a user to select a file for running the next script

Tags: python

If you create a button that executes an `askfilename`, how can i make the program wait for the user to push the button, select the file and  later  make use of that file name in other routine, that because the script will execute that next line routine and generate an error because didn't find the file variable defined .

i have no code for that but i think its a way for capture the filename and use it in for example `xlrd` module  for `open_workbook`

Comment: What GUI library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As Blender commented you havn't told us what GUI you're using. If you're using Tkinter then it will automatically wait till the user presses ok or cancel.

Try this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

name = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a file...")
if( name != "" ):
    print( name )
else:
    print( "User canceled" )
```